# Using list comprehension to add elements to a string from a reference dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dict as follows:

```
s = {'lorem': set(['test1', 'test2'])}
```

and a text file as follows:

```
data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

I wrote a script as follows:

```
[[word, s[word]] if word in s else word for word in data.lower().split()]
```

which outputs a list that looks like the following:

```
[['lorem', set(['test1', 'test2'])], 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit']
```

How can I rewrite the above script to output the following list:

```
['lorem', 'test1', 'test2', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'onsectetur', 'adipscing', 'elit']
```

Comment: @TheoretiCAL - yes, absolutely want to keep the original "lorem"

Comment: Then it's not considered as "replace" but rather, adding words. Please correct the description because it's misleading.

Comment: ok @alfasin - will update to reflect this.

Comment: Doing everything in one line doesn't make it run faster, more readable or easier to maintain. Please keep that in mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *unwrap* the set on the right side of the list comprehension. Use `dict.get` instead of testing for containment of the item in the dict:

```
lst = [w for word in data.lower().split() for w in [word] + list(s.get(word, ()))]
print(lst)
# ['lorem', 'test1', 'test2', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit']
```

Comment: Thats cool! I didn't realize you could do it that way... awesome, so elegant... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain
s = {'lorem': set(['test1', 'test2'])}

data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit"

new_data = [[i, list(s[i.lower()])] if i.lower() in s else [i] for i in data.split()]
final_data = list(chain.from_iterable([list(chain.from_iterable([[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else c for c in i])) if any(isinstance(b, list) for b in i) else i for i in new_data]))
```

Output:

```
['Lorem', 'test1', 'test2', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit']
```